# rpm-maven-plugin and OS X

Tags: java, maven, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, rpm-maven-plugin

I'm trying to set up a maven project on OSX and use the `rpm-maven-plugin` to build it as an RPM package. However, even the simplest configuration of the plugin seems to fail. The error I get is `Bad exit status from /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.10/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.50667 (%install)`. The verbose output doesn't give very much information. The generated spec file looks like this:

```
Name: server
Version: 1.0
Release: SNAPSHOT20130920084527
Summary: MySummary
License: 2013 MyCompany
Distribution: MyDistribution
Group: Application/SomeGroup
Packager: me
autoprov: yes
autoreq: yes
Prefix: /app/theapp
BuildRoot: /Users/me/Projects/projectname/server/target/rpm/server/buildroot

%description
My Description

%install
if [ -e $RPM_BUILD_ROOT ];
then
  mv /Users/me/Projects/projectname/server/target/rpm/server/tmp-buildroot/*         $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
else
  mv /Users/me/Projects/projectname/server/target/rpm/server/tmp-buildroot $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
fi

%files
%defattr(644,-,-,755)
  "/"
```

The command that builds the RPM is `/usr/local/bin/rpmbuild -vvv -bb --target noarch --buildroot /Users/me/Projects/projectname/server/target/rpm/server/buildroot --define '_topdir /tmp' server.spec`

I'm not really sure if it's an OSX problem or a general rpm-maven-plugin problem, but I suspect it is an OSX problem since I have been building RPMs with the rpm-maven-plugin on other platforms.

Have anyone else succeeded in using the `rpm-maven-plugin` on OSX?

**Edit**

I'm using `rpm-maven-plugin` 2.1-alpha-3, OS X 10.8.4 and installed rpm via homebrew. I have also verified that the same config works on a CentOS Vagrant box.

Comment: Which version of rpm-maven-plugin, MAC OS X, which version of RPM, how did you install rpmbuild on MacOS ? fink ports or how?

Comment: I have updated the question with details about versions. Thanks.